# Repeater ItemTemplate and DataBinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have some .ascx and its code behind. I am using `Repeater` with my `ItemTemplate` there.
So the question is - in which moment this template is assigned to my repeater?

Regards, Dmirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it helps I found ones this information about it here: [ASP.NET Web Server Controls Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h59db326%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which is on a full answer for your question, but maybe helps:

> A templated control creates an instance of its template contents only **on demand**. This means that instances of the controls in the template might not be created when the page load event occurs. This behavior can affect how a control inside a template can be used; you cannot assume that a control instance inside a template has been created when the page is loaded.